# How to load correct version of numpy in pyspark?

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark

I am working on AWS EC2 instance in master node for my pyspark application. The inbuilt python is 3.6.8 when I load pyspark from shell. However, the numpy version is 1.14.5.

In a separate folder structure, I have created a virtualenv and installed numpy 1.19.5 in it. Now, when I load numpy from within my pyspark application, it still returns me 1.14.5.

How do I tell my pyspark application to look in the virtual env's folder structure to load correct version of numpy.?

Steps -

```
python3 -m venv tutorial-env
source tutorial-env/bin/activate
pip install pandas==1.0.5
pip install pycaret==2.3
pip install boto3
deactivate
```

Once I exit virtual env, then I run my pyspark from shell which uses inbuilt python3. But I want it to use my virtualenv's python so that I can load the libraries from my virtualenv.

```
(tutorial-env) [hadoop@ip~]$ pyspark
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct 14 2019, 21:22:53) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
21/03/31 16:17:24 WARN HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.server2.thrift.url does not exist
21/03/31 16:17:26 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.4
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.8 (default, Oct 14 2019 21:22:53)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> import sys
>>> 
>>> sys.path.insert(1, '/home/hadoop/tutorial-env/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/')
>>> 
>>> import pycaret
>>> import numpy as np1
>>> np1.__version__
'1.14.5'
>>> import os
>>> os.system('pip install --upgrade numpy')
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./tutorial-env/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.19.5)
0
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.14.5'
```

How do I load the correct version of numpy ?

```
(tutorial-env) [hadoop@ip ~]$ pip list | grep numpy
numpy                     1.19.5
```